# AngularJS store array in a factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs, factory

I'm trying to cleanup my code and move some of it out of the controller. One example is to move list of states to a factory which looks like

```
'use strict';

myApp.factory('statesFactory', function(){
    return {

    data: { [
                { abbr: 'AL', name: 'Alabama' },
                { abbr: 'AK', name: 'Alaska' },
                { abbr: 'AZ', name: 'Arizona' },
                { abbr: 'AR', name: 'Arkansas' },
                ....                
                { abbr: 'WI', name: 'Wisconsin' },
                { abbr: 'WY', name: 'Wyoming' }
        ]}
    };
});
```

and then call it from related controller as

```
$scope.states = statesFactory.data;
```

but somehow I can't pass an array as a `data` in that case.

Comment: you have a syntax error, those `;` inside the returned object

Comment: @yBrodsky I have cleared that but now I'm getting `Unexpected token ,` after first set inside an array

Comment: well, you have another error: It should be `data: [ {abbr: 'AL', name: '..'} ... ]` You have an extra pair of `{ }`

Comment: OK, that did the job. You can post it as an answer. Thanks!